# Setting up integration within a truncated octahedron

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am trying to set up a triple integral over a region bounded by a truncated octahedron (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron). This surface is described by the intersection of 14 surfaces, given by the equations
$$|x|+ |y| + |z| = \frac{3}{2}$$
$$|x| = 1$$
$$|y| = 1$$
$$|x| = 1$$
where the first equation describes the 8 hexagonal faces, and the remaining three equations describe the 6 square faces. My attempt at this is to set up the integral of a function $f(x,y,z)$ as $$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-h(z)}^{h(z)} \int_{-g(y,z)}^{g(y,z)} f(x,y,z) dxdydz$$

with $$g(y,z) = \text{min} \{1,\frac{3}{2}-|y|-|z| \}$$
$$h(z) = \text{min} \{1, \frac{3}{2}-|z|\} .$$

Setting the integrand to $f=1$, I should get the volume of the region $V=4$, but this is not the case. Where am I going wrong with the bounds of integration?

Comment: Is this an exercise in integration, otherwise why not decompose it into tetrahedra?

Comment: @Chrystomath No, I am using Gaussian quadrature to compute this numerically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first octant, we would integrate $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{\min(1, 3/2-x)} \int_{z=0}^{\min(1, 3/2-x-y)} f(x,y,z) \, dV. \tag{1}$$  So by symmetry, the full volume is
$$\int_{x=-1}^1 \int_{y=-\min(1, 3/2-|x|)}^{\min(1, 3/2-|x|)} \int_{z=-\min(1, 3/2-|x|-|y|)}^{\min(1, 3/2-|x|-|y|)} f(x,y,z) \, dV. \tag{2}$$  This is the same as what you have, except with a change in order of integration.

I do not recommend evaluating $(2)$ directly, because it is incredibly tedious.  Rather, I recommend evaluating $(1)$ and exploiting symmetry, knowing that the latter arises naturally from the former.  This would give
$$\begin{align}
\frac{V}{8} &= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{\min(1, 3/2-x)} \min(1, 3/2-x-y) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \int_{y=0}^{1/2-x} 1 \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \int_{y=1/2-x}^1 \frac{3}{2}-x-y \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=1/2}^1 \int_{y=0}^{3/2-x} \frac{3}{2} - x - y \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \frac{1}{2} - x \, dx + \int_{x=0}^{1/2} \frac{3+4x-4x^2}{8} \, dx + \int_{x=1/2}^1 \frac{(3-2x)^2}{8} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{8} + \frac{11}{48} + \frac{7}{48} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}$$